# appcombat_v7 and missing AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

I just managed to successfully install Eclipse and even set up an AVD.
To get started I created a project, but there are two things I wondered about.

Eclipse created a folder `appcombat_v7` above my actual project. I've never seen this happen before (like in youtube-videos, or so)

The other thing is, when I wanted to run my project on my AVD it said there was an error that I have to fix first. Eclipse told me `AndroidManifest.xml` is missing. It really was, I cleaned the project, that solved the issue. I wonder why it was missing though. Is that normal?

Thanks in advance. Philip

Comment: does nobody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

This appcombat_v7 is something that comes with the latest version of SDK, this happedned with my workspace also when i updated to the SDK.
Also it automatically adds the fragment part.